# I want to display the sum of database column in another page in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I created a quiz and displayed that in one per page and check answer is correct or not and add 1 in database else 0 it for user_id 3

```
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
| id | answer | questions_id | user_id | exam_group_id | modules_id | marks | 
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | ans1   |            1 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     1 |
|  2 | ans2   |            2 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     1 |
|  3 | ans3   |            3 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     0 |   
|  4 | ans2   |            4 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     0 |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
```

i want the sum of the marks column to be displayed in admin login, user_id 1
in controller

```
@answers = Answer.find(:all)
@total = @answers.map(&:marks).sum
```

in view

```
<%= @total || '-' %>
```

it displays only - not @total

Comment: `@total` is nil in your view, so `'-'` is displayed. The question is why; Is `@answers` populated and does `@answers.map(&:marks).sum` actually sum the values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what `@answers` is or how it was calculated. Regardless, I'm assuming the table above is the quizzes table.

If so, please try:

```
@total = Answer.sum(:marks, :conditions => {:user_id => [3]})
```

Or

```
@total = Answer.where(:user_id => [3]).sum :marks
```

Comment: Just to confirm now that the question has been updated, is this table we're seeing above called Answer? as in `answer.rb`?